# How do I create an Alexa skill that gives the answers from my own database

Tags: database, alexa-skills-kit

I am learning about Alexa skills and eventually I want to create a skill although I need alexa's responds to the users being from a database that I am going to build. I was wondering if someone can give me some tips or recommend me a tutorial or reference which I can learn from.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a tutorial I wrote that covers how to build an Alexa Skill that returns data from a lookup table embedded in an AWS Lambda:

http://www.davidgyoungtech.com/2018/04/23/building-voice-bots-with-amazon-alexa

What you want to do requires only one additional step:  access the data from a database instead of the embedded lookup table.  For that, it all depends on what kind of database you want to use.  If you stick with Amazon's AWS tools and want to use their Dynamo DB to host your data, you can use the ScoreKeeper reference app to see how you read data from a AWS Dynamo DB from a Lambda: https://github.com/georgechapman/alexa-skills/tree/master/samples/scoreKeeper

Comment: Thank you David for your response, so does it mean that I can use alexa skills to fill out a form and save the user's responses in a database?

Comment: Yes, this is possible, although the traditional concept of "filling out a form" is awkward for a voice interface, as you need to verify all required fields are filled with valid values.  A more common voice approach is to design the voice not to  ask the user for follow up questions one at a time for each field.